# IE not loading page with Javascript and Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, raphael

I'm testing out a website that runs fine on Firefox (Win/Mac), Chrome (Win/Mac) and Safari. I'm having difficulty with Internet Explorer unfortunately. I get the following error message:

```
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
raphael-min.js, line 8 character 64961
```

I've taken a look at the debug output which looks like just takes me to a part of the [Raphel](http://raphaeljs.com/) library:

```
c=a.getScreenCTM()||a.createSVGMatrix()
```

I've searched for this error message online, but I don't understand what solution is relevant to this case as I've no idea what is causing the problem. I am also using the jQuery library. Are there any tests that I can do that can give me more information about the source of the problem?

Comment: Any chance you can post a link or crest a fiddle that reproduces the problem?  Also, what version of IE are you testing against?

Comment: Try using the non-minified Raphael library; it would be easier to get some idea of the context.

Comment: Which version of internet explorer?

Comment: What is your `javascript` and `raphaeljs` code you have used... I doubt this is a problem with `raphael`, more likely your JS code.

Comment: I can't figure out how to create a fiddle as I have many different pieces that I don't know how to include. I'm using IE 8. It looks like IE does not like when a variable is declared without using `var`. A few of these crept in when I was using Raphael (though I'm not sure this is the only problem).

Answer (score 5):

I just found how to patch this, in order to keep the compressed version of Raphael.

Replace (don't forget the coma):

```
c=a.getScreenCTM()||a.createSVGMatrix(),
```

By that (dont't forget the end space):

```
c;try{c=a.getScreenCTM()||a.createSVGMatrix()}catch(e){c=a.createSVGMatrix()};var
```

Works fine ! :)

---

Means :

1. `c;` : declaration of variable c, and stop the first instruction.
2. `try{c=a.getScreenCTM()||a.createSVGMatrix()}catch(e){c=a.createSVGMatrix()};` : our instruction, surrounded by a try/catch, to avoid IE error
3. `var` + a space : (don't forget the space!) allow us to continue to declare variable

Answer (score 3):

I found out that it's an issue with compression (of the js file). I had the exact same issue and I had been searching for a solution. Guess what? I tried it with the uncompressed Raphael file and voila! No more issues. Compressed file needs a tweak, it seems.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback : in my case, using the uncompressed version solved the problem, witch occur on IE9.

Comment: Glad to know the problem (and the solution) was the same. I hope a newer compressed version with that issue fixed gets uploaded sometime soon.